# What should I do to use place instead pack?

Tags: python, tkinter

How I can to use `place()` instead `pack()`?

```
tk.Label(frame, text='Label %i' % i).pack() # ==> tk.Label(frame, text='Label %i' % i).place(x=400,y=50*i)
```

When I use to `place()` instead `pack()` the Labels disappear from windows.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)

frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
# resize the canvas scrollregion each time the size of the frame changes
frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
# display frame inside the canvas
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor="nw")

scrolly = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
scrolly.place(relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1, anchor='ne')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrolly.set)

#################################
#Only this I want to use place() instead pack().
# populate the frame
for i in range(20):
    tk.Label(frame, text='Label %i' % i).pack() # ==> tk.Label(frame, text='Label %i' % i).place(x=400,y=50*i)
#################################

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `frame.config(width=..., height=...)` or specify the width and height when creating the frame. I would also advise you don't switch to `.place`.

Comment: What's wrong with using `pack`? Why do you think you need to use `place`? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: When I do to use frame.config(width= . . ., height= . . .) Still  the Labels disappear from windows.

Comment: @יובליובל They shouldn't. What width/height did you use?

Comment: I used frame.config(width=400, height=400).

Comment: @יובליובל So the frame has a width of 400 and you place all of the labels at `x=400`. That means that you aren't going to see them. Try setting the width to something bigger.

Comment: Thank you bro, I did not notice his my x value was great from 400.